# web2py:  How can I execute code before calling the controllers?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, modularity, web2py

In web2py, is there a way to have a piece of common code be executed before all controllers are called?

For example, I want to add some code that will log client IPs to a log of requests to enable analysis.   I could simply make the first line of all my controllers be something like `response = RequestBase(request)` but I'm curious to know if this is a problem that's already been solved through some other mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply put your piece of logging code in the model definition file, `models/db.py`, or in your controller `controllers/default.py` like this:

```
with open("mylog.log", "at") as f:
    f.write(repr(request))

def index():
    # index controller definition

# ... rest of the code
```

or, if you need functions or classes to be defined:

```
# --------------------------
# Log part:
# --------------------------

def my_log(request):
    with open("mylog.log", "at") as f:
        f.write(repr(request))

my_log(request)

# --------------------------
# Controllers part:
# --------------------------

def index():
    # index controller definition

# ... rest of the code
```

Of course, `repr(request)` is not how you want it, but you get the idea: from there you can log any information you like before the controllers are called (they are just defined at this stage).

The server already maintains a log in the root directory, in `httpserver.log`.

Answer (score 3):

Place the code in a model file and it will get executed before any controllers. If you only want the code to execute for a specific controller, place it at the top of the controller before any functions.